# О пегой масти

Tags: этимология

Здесь как-то уже звучал вопрос о названиях мастей лошадей, но есть еще масть, называемая пегой. И мне интересно: слово "пегий" происходит от слова "пегас" или наоборот? Дело в том, что пегаса чаще всего изображают пятнистым, то есть, пегой масти.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Между именем собственным Пегас и названием масти пегий нет никакой связи. **Пегас** - греч. Πήγάσος, в словаре Фасмера *пегас* трактуется как "определенная рыба" (???). О дальнейшей этимологии слова найти сведения не удалось.

Что касается слова **пегий**, то оно пришло в русский язык из ст.-слав. пѢгъ,    пѢготивъ,  пѢгота. Ср. в некоторых славянских языках пега - 'веснушка'. Слово родственно др.-инд. piŋktē "рисует" , piŋgas - "рыжеватый, коричневый", лат. pingo, pinхi, pictum, -еrе "рисовать; расшивать, вышивать", греч. πίγγαλος "ящерица". Далее восходит к *роig-, родственному и.-е.* реik- (писать). Отсюда современное англ. picture, название древнего племени *пикты* 'раскрашенные люди' и пр. Пегий значит 'рябой, веснушчатый, раскрашенный'.